# Archaic terminology: "algebra with order $n$"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I've been reading what's available as a Google books preview of "The Theory of Group Characters and Matrix Representations of Groups" by D. E. Littlewood. This book is from the 1950 and contains a lot of non-standard terminology. In particular the author refers to "the order of an algebra". This term isn't defined in the sections that I can view but I'm under the impression that "order" means "cardinality of generating set" i.e.

"the algebra $A$ has order 1" is equivalent to "the algebra $A$ is generated by a single element".

Has anyone seen this terminology before?

Comment: I'd guess that the order of an algebra refers to the number of elements it contains.

Comment: You mean the cardinality of the underlying vector space? I get the impression from reading the book that this is not the case. That would mean there are no algebras of order 1, since an algebra would have to have at least as many elements as the underlying field. My original guess was that order meant dimension of the underlying vector space but this doesn't seem right either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the dimension of the algebra (see the beginning of Chapter 2 ("Algebras")).

Comment: Thanks, I don't have that chapter. Just to make sure, you mean the dimension of the underlying vector space?

Comment: @Nostromo that depends on what the algebra is an algebra _over_. For instance, $\Bbb C^2$ has dimension $2$ as a $\Bbb C$-algebra, but dimension $4$ as a $\Bbb R$-algebra. But yes, basically. In nice cases, it's the number of elements in a basis.

Comment: @Nostromo Yes. He seems to be talking only about algebras over $\mathbb{C}$, and defines an algebra of order $n$, very concretely, to be the set of complex vectors with $n$ coordinates, together with $n^3$ complex numbers as structure constants. So for him an "algebra of order $n$" is $\mathbb{C}^n$ with a bilinear binary operation.